# Firebase Firestore Getting documents again on query stream

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection(
        'chats/${site}/conversations/${room.id}/messages')
    .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
    .where("createdAt", isGreaterThan: dateTime )
    .snapshots()
    .map(
  (snapshot) {
```

So, On the first document that inserted to the firestore, the I get i a snapshot. On the second, the stream return the first and the second,
So the i get -
(Doc A)
(Doc A,Doc B)
(Doc A, Doc B, Doc C)

And so on. Is there a way to get:
(Doc A)
(Doc B)
(Doc C)
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for everyone who reach this issue on 2022, the solution is rather simple.
You can stay with the same query but check the doc changes:

```
snapshot.docChanges.forEach((docChange) {
        final data = docChange.doc.data() as Map;
```

LimitToLast won't solve your problem if the internet connection was down for a few moments and multiple updates arrived, but docChanges is all the changes since the last snapshot.
Note: You need to ignore the first time because it will return all the docs on the collection at the first time.

Answer (score 1):

I reviewed your snippet and it appears you are using a `Stream` from the `snapshot()` method of a `CollectionReference` type. According to the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#realtime-changes), this will stream events as they happen in Firestore. You mentioned that with each document inserted in Firestore, you also started getting the previous documents that were inserted before, instead of getting only the one which was just inserted (the latest). This might be related to the `dateTime` variable you are using to filter documents. Since you are using a greater than comparison, any documents created after the time set in the dateTime will be returned from the query. This could explain why your query returns additional documents each time a new one is added with a timestamp after the `dateTime` variable.

If you would like to get only the latest document added to the database each time, you can make use of a [query limiter](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#limiting). I tested the `limitToLast` [method](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/limitToLast.html) to get only the latest document added and it appears to work in my testing. This method returns the very last document in a query, and in order for this to be the newest you would have to invert the process to order by ascending (oldest first) so that the newest document is at the bottom:

```
FirebaseFirestore firebase = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
firebase
    .collection('users')
    .orderBy('createdAt', descending: false) // orders by ascending order, latest document is the last
    .limitToLast(1) // gets the last document, you can set how many docs to get
    .get()
    .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
  if (snapshot != null) {
    // Data is available
    snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
      print(doc['firstName']);
    });
  } else {
    print("No data found");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply!
If there are 2 docs added quickly to the collection, will limit to last still returns both?

Comment: The `limitToLast()` method will return as many documents as you set in the argument. In my example, it will be only 1, regardless if there are two documents uploaded closely together, since it looks at the ordering of the `createdAt` field which probably contains a timestamp. There are additional limiters in the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#start--end-cursors) if you want different behavior.