# Firestore document is read multiple times after a single update in Firebase emulator

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I am using Firestore to save users data.  Each user in my app has a stream that listens to the user's document.  I am running Firestore emulator and noticed that SOMETIMES after the user document is updated, document is read twice or more.  I have attached an image from the Firestore emulator that shows that.  Is there a reason why I am getting multiple reads after a single update.  I am not doing any read to the user document outside the stream.

[image]

I am using Flutter mobile app for watching the user document ".snapshots()".  The print statement in this code prints only one read.  But if I am reading the user document only in the stream, then how do I end up with 2 reads in the emulator?

```
  Stream<MyProfile?> watchMyProfile() {
    return _firestore
        .doc(PathService.user(uid))
        .withConverter<MyProfile>(
          fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) {
            return MyProfile.fromJson(snapshot.data()!);
          },
          toFirestore: (myProfile, _) => myProfile.toJson(),
        )
        .snapshots()
        .map((doc) => doc.data())
        .map(
      (myProfile) {
        // THIS ONLY PRINTS ONCE.
        debugPrint('watchMyProfile - read my profile');
        return myProfile;
      },
    );
  }
```

UPDATE 1:
To make sure that I am not reading any user document after update in firestore.rules file, I used something like this:

```
allow update: if true;
allow get: if true;
allow list: if true;
```

Unfortunately, I am still seeing lots of reads after an update to the user document.

[image]

Comment: Is this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70823997/20239914) helpful for you? and you can check this [doc](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/database/lists-of-data) which explains the scenirio you are looking for

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.  I am using FireStore not realtime database.  Also I am dealing with a single document.  Each user is listening to his/her document.  I am not dealing with list of documents.

Comment: can you have a look at my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced the issue at my end and found the same behavior. As you can see in the image provided, reads have increased significantly.

[image]

This is due to constructing the stream inside a stream. It will get re-created on each call to build(), up to 60 times per second if there's an animation on the page.

I recommend you to construct the stream in a private variable then use it in the stream so it will not get re-created on each build method and will be called only once.

Something like this

```
class SomeClass extends State<Some_State>{
    final Stream<MyProfile> _usersStream =             
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc('ABC123').snapshots();
    
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<MyProfile>(
      stream: _usersStream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
        //…
  }
}
```

For reference,
Real time updates on a document is done by StreamBuilder as shown in [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#realtime-changes)